# Typescript Inteface where "id" must be number and other properties must be string

Tags: typescript

I need to define a interface for a data which comes from the server where `id` in  a number, but all other properties are strings.

I tried:

```
interface AnyChartsData {
  id: number;
  [key: string]: string;
}
```

but i got this error:

> [ts] Property 'id' of type 'number' is not assignable to string index type 'string'. [2411]

How can I define this interface properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a union type since `id` is a number and not a string e.g.

```
interface AnyChartsData {
    id: number;
    [key: string]: string | number;
}
```